# Map.keySet() read sequence?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, android-8.0-oreo, keyset

I have `Map<String, List<String>> map` now, putting two values inside Map,  now when read keyset from map gives in different sequence in different device.

```
private Map<String, List<String>>  map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("First", new ArrayList<String>());
map.put("Second", new ArrayList<String>());
```

Now, Read keys from this map.

```
 Set<String> keys = map.keySet();

 for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
     Log.d("key", keys.toArray()[i].toString());
 }
```

**OUTPUT IN OREO 8.0**

```
D/Key : First
D/Key : Second
```

**OUTPUT in BELOW 8.0**

```
D/Key : Second
D/Key : First
```

Comment: Um, a `Set` has no defined order. You are getting a `Set` from `keySet()`; you should make no assumptions at all about the order of elements in that `Set`.

Comment: yeah , but how it is possible to read it in different order basically it;s happen  in only in Oreo 8

Comment: Again, you should make no assumptions at all about the order of elements in that `Set`. If you want them to be in some order, convert the `Set` to an `ArrayList`, then sort the `ArrayList` by your desired order.

Comment: Okay thanks  @CommonsWare

Comment: @CommonsWare maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    } this is take too much time for compile is there any solution ?

Comment: I do not know what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Have you develop this Lib url "s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com ??

Comment: That is the Maven-style repository for my CWAC libraries.

Comment: Thanks Can you please tell me that whenever i change something in gradle its download every time and it is too time consuming so, have you any solution ? @CommonsWare

Comment: Um, don't use libraries from that repository, I guess.

Comment: what is alternate of this ? Are you working at Google / Amazon @CommonsWare ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution until we defined Set as SortedSet ,we getting key sequence in different order.

```
SortedSet<String> keys =  new TreeSet<>(map.keySet());

for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
    Log.d("key", keys.toArray()[i].toString());            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `HashMap` as the data structure. As in `HashMap`, the order of insertion is not maintained thus you're getting a random order of the keys. If you want to maintain the order of insertion, simply use a `LinkedHashMap`. The order in which you put the data is maintained and simply you can iterate over it.

**Sample code for `LinkedHashMap`:**

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("key1", "value2");
    map.put("key3", "value4");
    map.put("key5", "value6");
    map.put("key7", "value8");
    Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
    for(String st: keySet){
        System.out.println(st);
    }
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

**Output:**

```
key1
key3
key5
key7
key1 value2
key3 value4
key5 value6
key7 value8
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the android OS. The resulting `Set` of `HashMap` has no order. However there are `Set`s with an order e.g. `TreeSet`.